# WPF datagrid dropdown two-way binding

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to get a dropdown column in a WPF datagrid (hosted in a user control derived from a base class called ControlBase) to bind properly.  It initially populates fine from the object, and a populated dropdown appears when I edit the cell, but a selected value does not get back into the cell when I leave focus.

Here's my model and domain objects:

```
 public class ModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
   public IList<Person> Persons { get; set; }
 }

 public class UserControlModel : ModelBase
 {
    public ObservableCollection<DatagridRecord> SourceData { get; set; }
 }

 public class Person
 {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
 }

 public class DatagridRecord
 {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Person ContactPerson { get; set; }
 }
```

And in my xaml.cs, I set the DataContext via a Model property:

```
 public UserControlModel _model;
 public UserControlModel Model
 {
  set
  {
    _model = value;
    DataContext = null;
    DataContext = _model;
  }
}
```

Here's my DataGrid column definition in xaml:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Person" >
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ContactPerson.Name}"/></DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Persons, 
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type uch:ControlBase}}}" 
                       DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                       SelectedValuePath="Id" />
        </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I figure there is something wrong with tying the combobox selected value to the grid row, but I've gone around in circles trying to hook it up.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Corey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're Missing a `SelectedItem` or `SelectedValue` binding:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Persons, 
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type uch:ControlBase}}}" 
                       DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                   --> SelectedItem="{Binding ContactPerson}" <--
                       SelectedValuePath="Id" />
```

Comment: Works! Thanks.  Is there anyway to have the cell contents already selected in the dropdown when I click the cell?  Otherwise when I click the cell,the dropdown shows an empty selection until I expand it.

Comment: You can use `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem`, and it will work that way, but, you need to have a `public int PersonId` property in the ViewModel.

Comment: The domain classes are POCO's for EF Code First.  Is EF smart enough to be able to have a PersonId property and a Person property in the class and not screw up the database schema?

Comment: I never used Code First, so I couldn't tell. Otherwise just add that as a regular property and populate it from the `ContactPerson.Id`

Comment: Apparently it is possible without screwing up the generated database.  You can have both the FK ID and a reference to the object when you use the [ForeignKey("fkname")] attribute.  Thanks again for all your help.